VBA Get Source Query of a View via ADODB Connection
I have a view in my SQL Server Express, and I want to modify the query that builds it through VBA.
Is it possible to get the source query and save it in a string?
Since I'd like to do some "find and replace" in it, is it also possible to do so directly on the view?
Ty
